# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject (in SOQL)

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, failing-tests

Trying to run a test class:

```
@isTest
public class UserRootTest {

    @isTest
    static void testRegNow (){
        Id guID = [SELECT GuestUserId FROM Site WHERE UrlPathPrefix = 'Tesla' LIMIT 1].GuestUserId;
        
        UserRoot.UserCreateResponse ucRes;
        
        System.runAs(new User(Id = guID)){
            RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
            RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
            req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/IdPUser';
            req.httpMethod = 'POST';
            req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            RestContext.request = req;
            RestContext.response= res;
            UserRoot.UserCreateRequest ucReq = new UserRoot.UserCreateRequest();

            ucReq.firstname = 'Test';
            ucReq.lastname = 'Test';
            
            
            ucRes = UserRoot.selfRegister(ucReq);
            
            User u = [SELECT Id, Title, Street FROM User
                     WHERE Id=:ucRes.userId];
            
            System.assertEquals(ucReq.title, u.Title);
            System.assertEquals(ucReq.addressStreet, u.Street);
    }  
        
        System.assertNotEquals(null, ucRes.userId);
        }
```

But getting:

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

Failing here:

```
User u = [SELECT Id, Title, Street FROM User
                         WHERE Id=:ucRes.userId];
```

Seems to be empty. I have tried to put it into try cat, but error remains. How should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.runAs(new User(Id = guID)){
```

You're not actually inserting a User, you're only creating a new instance of one. If you want to be able to query for that user they need to be inserted.

Comment: But when I pass only System.runAs(guID) it gives me error runAs requires a single argument of type 'User' or 'Version'. What should I do?

Comment: I actually might have been a bit hasty as I now see the user you're probably querying for a different user. You should edit your post to include the details of UserRoot class as well.